# How to switch language in chrome settings by clicking on an icon

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to switch English(US) to Japanese and vise versa. Click on an extensions icon and switch this languages. How can I solve this problem?

[Here](http://s16.postimg.org/go8p3sipx/lang.png) is screenshot of what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I Cant Understand your question Clearly ,
Hope this helps some
Try this Extension [Google Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb?hl=en)

Comment: No, I don't need to translate content of page. I need to change the language of Google Chrome. I need this, because my web-application works on both languages (Eng and Japanese) and it's takes too much time to switch the language manually when I need to see how does my app looks in another language. I didn't find any existing solutions, so I want to create my own.

Comment: I understand now,, but u want to close and open your browser to make the language settings affect the browser every time.

Answer (score 0):

I had create a sort of what you are thinking hope it helps

here the manifest and Js file for the extension.

every time u click it will leads to  **chrome://settings/languages**

**manifest.json**

```json
{
    "name": "Language Settings",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Open Language Settings",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: "chrome://settings/languages"
    });
});
```